# RestKit - Handling authentication

Tags: ios, web-services, rest, authentication, restkit

I've begun working on the proof-of-concept for an iOS application that we'll be developing that leverages REST-based web services (implemented in Java using restEASY).  I will be using RestKit as my client-side services library, and have been reading up on the documentation and some examples.

The vast majority of the services will require that a user be authenticated with a username and password.  We have authentication services in place that accept a JSON object containing the credentials, so that part is easy.  My question is, how do we handle the iOS piece when a service says that authentication is required?

Imagine this scenario...

A user starts up our app and it recognizes that the user needs to authenticate.  A modal view controller pops up, prompts the user for authentication, and submits the request.  The user is then able to make a bunch of REST calls with no problem.  Eventually, they turn off their phone (app is still active) and come back to it an hour or so later.  They click a button to fire off another REST call, but by this time the server-side session has expired.

Ideally, we'd like to be able to recognize that the server has indicated authentication is required, and pop up the modal view controller again.  But, does RestKit have support for this?  Is there any way for us to register a "global response handler" that is able to recognize that the server has responded this way?

We can return a status code in JSON or use an HTTP status code.  We have flexibility on our services.  The real question is how to handle this in the ideal way on the client.  And, once we've reauthenticated the user, is there any way to replay the request they originally tried to submit?  Or, would they have to kick off the action again?

Sorry if this doesn't make sense or if it's a very simple problem to solve.  As I'm just getting started with RestKit, I wanted to make sure I was doing this the right way to avoid future problems.  Any advice, code samples, tutorials, etc. that you can provide would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you make a request to the server in your AppDelegate
`- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` or
`- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` method that sends the old authentication token. The server can then provide a response if the token is valid or invalid.
If your AppDelegate adopts the RKObjectLoaderDelegate protocol then it can handle the response. That way, whenever the application becomes active, the user is prompted to re-authenticate if necessary.